# Could'nt able to recognize the mistake in the code, my file or directory of the dataset is'nt able to open?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

DATADIR = "F:/Datasets/PetImages"

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

for category in CATEGORIES:  

    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
    for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it
        plt.show()  # display!

        break  # we just want one for now so break
    break  #...and one more!
```

and my error is :

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-7de22e8bce3a> in <module>()
     11 for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats
     12     ath = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
---> 13     for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
     14         img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
     15         plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:/Datasets/PetImages/Dog'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly download your data into colab from your local drive. You can import from google drive. You can technically use your local drive but it's still uploading it to drive.